# How to convert the string to JSON in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

when i fetch the data from firebase real time database, i am getting string object like below. May i know how can i convert this to JSON object?. how can i get the data like **Address:"Add line 1, Add line 2, Street,City,State.".** ?. This is for my react native app.

**What i tried:**

- when i tried to use JSON.parse, i am getting the error 'JSON Parse
  error: Unexpected token: o'.
- when i display the data, it is [object object]
- when i try typeof, i am getting result as object

**data that i get from Firebase real time database(It is getting displayed like below when i use JSON.stringify):**

```
user:{"Address":"Add line 1, Add line 2, Street,City,State.","Age":"42","CAppoint":{"0":{"AppointDate":"","ConsultDoc":"","Patient":"C1","Slot":"","Treatment":"","extra1":"","extra2":""}},"PAppoint":{"0":{"AppointDate":"","ConsultDoc":"","Patient":"P1","Slot":"","Treatment":"","extra1":"","extra2":""},"1":{"AppointDate":"","ConsultDoc":"","Patient":"P2","Slot":"","Treatment":"","extra1":"","extra2":""},"2":{"AppointDate":"","ConsultDoc":"","Patient":"P3","Slot":"","Treatment":"","extra1":"","extra2":""},"3":{"AppointDate":"","ConsultDoc":"","Patient":"P4","Slot":"","Treatment":"","extra1":"","extra2":""}},"name":"Zulu","pass":"1234","phone":"+918888888888"}
```

**how i fetch data from firebase:**

```
const readUserData = async (phoneNumber) => {
try {
      const reference = ref(db, 'x123456/' + phoneNumber);
      return (await get(reference)).toJSON((snapshot) => {
          const data = snapshot.val();
          console.log('DATA: ' + data);
      }, (error) => {
          console.error(error);
          return 0;
      });
}
```

### How i call the above function:

````
      exist=await readUserData('+91'+phoneNumber);
      console.log('user:'+ JSON.stringify(exist));
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error);
    }```
````

Comment: You have a javascript object in `exist`, which you can access via its keys. So just use `exist.Address` or `exist.Name` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is the answer you want :

```js
var obj_str = '{"Address":"Add line 1, Add line 2, Street,City,State.","Age":"42","CAppoint":{"0":{"AppointDate":"","ConsultDoc":"","Patient":"C1","Slot":"","Treatment":"","extra1":"","extra2":""}},"PAppoint":{"0":{"AppointDate":"","ConsultDoc":"","Patient":"P1","Slot":"","Treatment":"","extra1":"","extra2":""},"1":{"AppointDate":"","ConsultDoc":"","Patient":"P2","Slot":"","Treatment":"","extra1":"","extra2":""},"2":{"AppointDate":"","ConsultDoc":"","Patient":"P3","Slot":"","Treatment":"","extra1":"","extra2":""},"3":{"AppointDate":"","ConsultDoc":"","Patient":"P4","Slot":"","Treatment":"","extra1":"","extra2":""}},"name":"Zulu","pass":"1234","phone":"+918888888888"}';

console.log(obj_str);

var obj = JSON.parse(obj_str);
console.log(obj);
```

or..

```js
var obj_str = '{"user":{"Address":"Add line 1, Add line 2, Street,City,State.","Age":"42","CAppoint":{"0":{"AppointDate":"","ConsultDoc":"","Patient":"C1","Slot":"","Treatment":"","extra1":"","extra2":""}},"PAppoint":{"0":{"AppointDate":"","ConsultDoc":"","Patient":"P1","Slot":"","Treatment":"","extra1":"","extra2":""},"1":{"AppointDate":"","ConsultDoc":"","Patient":"P2","Slot":"","Treatment":"","extra1":"","extra2":""},"2":{"AppointDate":"","ConsultDoc":"","Patient":"P3","Slot":"","Treatment":"","extra1":"","extra2":""},"3":{"AppointDate":"","ConsultDoc":"","Patient":"P4","Slot":"","Treatment":"","extra1":"","extra2":""}},"name":"Zulu","pass":"1234","phone":"+918888888888"}}';

console.log(obj_str);

var obj = JSON.parse(obj_str);
console.log(obj);
```

**JSON required start with '{' and end with '}'**.
(also required 'key' enclosed in quotation marks, like "user")

Comment: I have already mentioned in my post what is the error that i am getting when i use JSON.parse. 
JSON.parse works for me when i have object like below(no double quote in element Address and Age). My actual data has double quote in all the keys as well as in values.

`{Address:"Add line 1, Add line 2, Street,City,State.",Age:42}`

Comment: Sorry, maybe I don't understand well.
The answer you want is Alijvhr's reply, maybe.

Answer (score 1):

**Your function return is an object already.**

So simply you can use your desired property:

```
try{
    const myuser = await readUserData('+91' + phoneNumber);
    console.log(myuser.Address);
} catch (error) {
    alert(error);
}
```

[More Info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_objects)